# 'Detach' from program terminal Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I mainly use Windows but was interested in messing around with Redis so I installed it on my netbook (running Ubuntu 12.10) and accessing it via SSH.

I would like to start the Redis server then leave it running while I use something else with the terminal. I am aware you can use Screen to do this but am wondering if is possible to do it without the use of Screen.

I hope this is understandable, I have almost never used Linux and have almost no idea of how to use it, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options:

1. `service start redis-server`
2. `/etc/init.d/redis-server start`
3. With upstart, `start redis-server`

Related Q&A: [How to start and stop a service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58404/how-to-start-and-stop-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your command in the background by putting an ampersand at the end like

> sudo longrunningtask &

To return a task to the forground, use the fg command. But of course if it's a system service use jweyrich's suggestions.